# Update or Change the button label in C

Tags: c, button, updates, glade, gtk2

For my GUI having some buttons. If I were to change or update the label of any random button I select from the list what should I do?

The initial name of the button is written in button properties. My GUI is designed in **Glade**.

And now I will enter the new name in entry-text in my GUI.

I have created an update button for this. How to do it in **Gtk** ofcourse.

The related codes are as follows:

Creation of button in the window and find it.

```
 UpdateButton = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "UpdateButton" ) );
 gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (UpdateButton), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (Update_Data), NULL);
```

On update button clicked.

```
 void Update_Data( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
    {
                    const gchar *entry_text1;
                    const gchar *entry_text2;
                    const gchar *entry_text3;

    g_print ("You have clicked Update... - %s was pressed\n", (char *) data);

             entry_text1 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry1));
             entry_text2 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry2));
             entry_text3 = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (entry3));

    char sql[300];
    sprintf(sql, "UPDATE DEVICES set NAME='%s ',\nUSERNAME='%s ',\nPASSWORD='%s '\nwhere ID=%s;"
               , entry_text1, entry_text2, entry_text3, updateid); 
    //updateid is the ID taken from the array when a button is clicked

       inserDatabase("myDatabase.db", sql);  
       getlastEntry(); //for taking the last entered info
       updateData(sql); //for updating in database
    }
```

If more information is required I will get you. Please do ask!

Answer (score 3):

*Your question is unclear, but if I understand you correctly...*

You get the buttons...

```
GtkButton *click_button; // Button to click
GtkButton *change_button; // Button that changes label

click_button = GTK_BUTTON (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "click_button"));
change_button = GTK_BUTTON (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "change_button"));
```

Define a function for the click event to set the label...

```
static void
change_button_label (GtkWidget *click_button,
                     gpointer   user_data)
{
    GtkButton *change_button = (GtkButton *) user_data;
    gtk_button_set_label (change_button, "New Label");
}
```

Connect the click signal function to the button, and pass it the change button...

```
g_signal_connect (click_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (change_button_label), change_button);
```

Comment: Ok @Coffee'd can you tell me now how to change the label when I enter the new name in entry-text?

Comment: @djgharphalia07 It depends. How are you getting and storing the text? For example, you can get the text like so: `const gchar *button_text = gtk_entry_get_text (text_entry);`, where `text_entry` is the `GtkEntry` widget. And then you just use `button_text` like so: `gtk_button_set_label (change_button, button_text);` This, however, would require `button_text` be a global variable, or storing both the `change_button` and the `text_entry` widget in a struct and passing that to the click signal function instead.

Comment: You are very close :) And I like to thank you for so quick response! Actually I am storing the buttons information in a database. So, updating will change in database too. I have done everything but I can't get the updated label in button after entered instead of running my codes again to get the new label:(

Comment: @djgharphalia07 You mean it's updating the database, but not updating the button label at the same time? Without reading the database again? I would probably need to see that portion of your source code to help.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Hmm. It's up to you. If you think it's related, edit your question. If it seems to be another question of it's own, ask it as a new question, that why more people can help answer it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89262/discussion-between-djgharphalia07-and-coffeed-up-hacker).